# Как отличить xpath от css селектора?

Tags: python-3.x

У класса есть два метода: `select_by_xpath` и `select_by_css`. Хочу дописать `__call__(rule)` в котором и выбирался бы нужный метод, но с xpath плотно не работал потому вопрос. Что нужно написать в if чтобы он правильно определили какой метод надо вызвать?

Comment: Правильно не получится, например `div` является одновременно и корректным css, и корректным xpath

Comment: @andreymal, для xpath, `div` будет правильный, если `div` корень xml, а если не корень, то для поиска на любом уровне вложенности нужно писать `//div`

Comment: Думаю, различить одно от другого сложно (но можно, например исключением символов одного запроса от другого, например запросы, начинающиеся на `.` или `#` скорее всего css-селектор), но проще и нагляднее указывать вид правила, а если это в GUI то добавить комбобокс с вариантами поиска: CSS-селектор/XPATH

Comment: @gil9red `div` в любом случае будет правильным xpath, просто в таком виде он никаких элементов не найдёт :) А вот например `html` будет одинаково работать и в css, и в xpath (если верить xpath'у моего фаерфокса)

Comment: А можно если есть / в строке то это xpath иначе css?